# How to retrieve Data Category Wise using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a products table with three columns **ID**, **Product** and **Category**.

I want to retrieve my product category wise like this..

**Category1**

Product1

Product2

Product3

Product4

**Category2**

Product1

Product2

Product3

Product4

**Category3**

Product1

Product2

Product3

Product4

I tried this...

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE status = 1";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if (@$result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $category = $row['category'];
        $name = $row['name'];

        foreach ($row as $category) 
        {
            echo $name."<br/>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

But its repeating each product a number of times...

Please Help !

Comment: Add an ORDER BY clause to your query to sort by category then product. Then use a break-sort in your php to display the categories'

Comment: Thats not working

Comment: What's not working? Edit your question to show what's not working

Comment: If you have a " table with three columns ID, Product and Category"  where does "status"  come from? I have the feeling you are leaving out some information about the true nature of the table and its structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to loop over results while keeping record of the last encountered category. 
See code below (untested):

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY category ASC, name ASC";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if (@$result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    $previous_category = ""   // To keep track of the last printed category
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $category = $row['category'];
        $name = $row['name'];

        if ($previous_category !== $category) { // If this category has never been printed, we print it
            echo $category."<br/>";
            $previous_category = $category;
        }

        echo $name."<br/>";
    }
}
?>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Add an ORDER BY clause so the categories are in the right order and the break sort works.

Comment: @SloanThrasher yes I think you're right, I was focusing more on the printing part. I will update my answer.
But just like Barns I have the feeling that we do not have the full table structure :/

Comment: Actually, this is a situation where you would want to use `GROUP BY`. But without knowing more detail about the data table structure the necessary sql query cannot be defined.

Comment: Coding a "filter" in a loop is extremely inefficient. Let the database handle it...that is what it was designed to do.